# Subset big data set using strings in two columns from other data set

Tags: r

In that case our big data set would look like:

```
structure(list(Car = c("Mazda RX4", "Maserati Bora", "Leticia", 
                       "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Alex", "Duster 360", 
                       "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", 
                       "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Lincoln Continental", 
                       "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", "Toyota Corolla", 
                       "Toyota Corona", "Datsun 710", "AMC Javelin", "Camaro Z28", 
                       "Datsun 710", "Fiat X1-9", "Mazda RX4", "Lotus Europa", 
                       "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Volvo 142E"
), Name = c("Mark", "Random", "Datsun 710", "Trevor", "Joanna", 
            "Valiant", "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random", 
            "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random", 
            "Random", "Trevor", "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random", 
            "Random", "Mazda RX4", "Random", "Alex", "Random", "John", "Random"
), disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225, 360, 146.7, 140.8, 
            167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472, 460, 440, 78.7, 75.7, 
            71.1, 120.1, 318, 304, 350, 400, 79, 120.3, 95.1, 351, 145, 301, 
            121), hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 
                         180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 150, 245, 
                         175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 109), drat = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.85, 
                                                                         3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 
                                                                         2.93, 3, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.7, 2.76, 3.15, 3.73, 3.08, 
                                                                         4.08, 4.43, 3.77, 4.22, 3.62, 3.54, 4.11), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 
                                                                                                                           2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 3.15, 3.44, 3.44, 4.07, 
                                                                                                                           3.73, 3.78, 5.25, 5.424, 5.345, 2.2, 1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.52, 
                                                                                                                           3.435, 3.84, 3.845, 1.935, 2.14, 1.513, 3.17, 2.77, 3.57, 2.78
                                                                         ), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 
                                                                                     20, 22.9, 18.3, 18.9, 17.4, 17.6, 18, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 
                                                                                     18.52, 19.9, 20.01, 16.87, 17.3, 15.41, 17.05, 18.9, 16.7, 16.9, 
                                                                                     14.5, 15.5, 14.6, 18.6), vs = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                     1), am = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gear = c(4, 4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                       4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                       3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4), carb = c(4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            6, 8, 2)), .Names = c("Car", "Name", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to subset this data set by extracting some rows from it. The rows which I would like to extract are stored in another data frame:

```
> dput(list_save)
structure(list(Car = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
"Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant"), Name = c("Mark", 
"John", "Leticia", "Trevor", "Joanna", "Alex")), .Names = c("Car", 
"Name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Take a look on the `list_save` because some of the strings can be found in a different column according to `df` but it has to be extracted as well.

The desired output should be something like that:

```
               Car       Name disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1         Mazda RX4       Mark  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2     Mazda RX4 Wag       John  301 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
3           Leticia Datsun 710  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4    Hornet 4 Drive     Trevor  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 Hornet Sportabout     Joanna  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6              Alex    Valiant  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I think about function similar to the one showed below:

```
test <- df[df[,1:2] %in% list_save, ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just run two binary joins using `data.table` once `Car` and `Name` against them selves and once against each other and just combine the too. We will be using the latest version on CRAN for this (v 1.9.6+)

```
library(data.table) # v 1.9.6+
res <- setDT(df)[list_save, on = c("Car", "Name")]
res2 <- df[list_save, on = c(Name = "Car", Car = "Name"), nomatch = 0L]
res[is.na(disp), (names(res)) := res2]
#                  Car       Name disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1:         Mazda RX4       Mark  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2:     Mazda RX4 Wag       John  301 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
# 3:           Leticia Datsun 710  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4:    Hornet 4 Drive     Trevor  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5: Hornet Sportabout     Joanna  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6:              Alex    Valiant  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

---

Alternatively, a safer approach would be just `rbind` only the matched results but this way you will lose the original rows order

```
res <- setDT(df)[list_save, on = c("Car", "Name"), nomatch = 0L]
res2 <- df[list_save, on = c(Name = "Car", Car = "Name"), nomatch = 0L]
rbind(res, res2)
#                  Car       Name disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1:         Mazda RX4       Mark  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2:     Mazda RX4 Wag       John  301 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
# 3:    Hornet 4 Drive     Trevor  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 4: Hornet Sportabout     Joanna  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 5:           Leticia Datsun 710  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 6:              Alex    Valiant  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sub_df <- df[which(df[,1] %in% list_save[,1] & df[,2] %in% list_save[,2]),]
```

Although, do you mean to have `Alex` in `Car` and `Valiant` in `Name`? I Only ask because the above assumes those were mistakes. If that isnt the case use:

**EDITED**

```
sub_df <-  df[which(df[,1] %in% list_save[,1] & df[,2] %in% list_save[,2] |
                    df[,1] %in% list_save[,2] & df[,2] %in% list_save[,1]),]
```

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with the code. If I use it for my original data it extracts every rows which contains any of the strings from the two columns.

Comment: without seeing your original data it would be hard to say, that works for the sample data.

Comment: Try now. Edited main data set. It is similar to the original one.